# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

Firefox version 32.0
Selenium webdriver 2.42.2/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2(both have same error)
Windows 7 x64
And i've checked port and it's free.

Comment: Selenium 2.42.2 supports FF31. Please downgrade your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is you should be downgrading your browser.

Selenium 2.42.2 supports only FF31. Wait till the next support is been released or downgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the compatibility of fire fox version and the selenium jar file version.Use the latest selenium jar files 2.52 is compatible with FF till 44.0.that can fix the problem.